# Google Map overlapping onto div below

Tags: html, css, node.js, reactjs, google-maps

I am trying to display the Google map between two divs, but the map seems to be overlapping with the div below it. I have tried a bunch of styles on the component, but it doesn't want to take up the full space and always overlaps with that next section. This might be because of the div within the component from the package that isn't being overwritten, which is what might be referenced by these issues:

- https://github.com/fullstackreact/google-maps-react/pull/208
- https://github.com/fullstackreact/google-maps-react/issues/298
- https://github.com/fullstackreact/google-maps-react/issues/335

Check out my Code Sandbox for the full example: https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-wildflower-zkt8b

Looking to find a quick work around for this, I feel like it shouldn't be this difficult for how common it is, so maybe I am missing something. Anything helps, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```js
class SimpleMap extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // Filling our parent container
    this.state = {
      mapStyles: {
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%"
      }
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      // Wrapping your component on a relative div container with the desired size
      <div style={{ position: 'relative', width: '100vw', height: '40vh' }}>
        <Map
          google={this.props.google}
          zoom={15}
          style={this.state.mapStyles}
          initialCenter={{ lat: 40, lng: -80 }}
        >
          <Marker position={{ lat: 40, lng: -80 }} />
        </Map>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Updated code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-babbage-31g3o).